Kingston SUV400S half dead after Orange Screen of Death
Some preface before getting into this mess.
2012-2015 Dell 7010 desktop with who knows what sort of cruel experiments performed on it by IT-students. Bought 2019 for cheap with mismatching ram sticks and a "new" Kingston SUV400S (suv400s37240g) and worked fine to this day with few issues. I also added an used Kingston A400 as it was running low (may not be relevant), so now to what happened.
I was watching some disc movies over the Christmas holidays and the computer worked fine for three days in a row. Today (27th) I decided to watch more movies, but the computer was very slow (1 minute to open task manager, another 1 for anything to show), so I killed some background processes and continued (may not be relevant). At some point the case vibrated enough for me to remove a USB Wifi dongle and all hell broke loose as I got the Orange Screen of Death and some error about display/graphics drivers.
The computer rebooted and showed a stuck black screen after briefly showing the automatic repair text. I installed another copy of Windows on the A400 and got into a fresh install. Now in the end the SUV400s doesn't show anywhere in Windows but does show in BIOS and Dell's hardware test without any issues.
Some of the things I've tried based on searches:

Swapping 3 sets of SATA and power cables
Diskpart (Doesn't show other drives as having free space(could be as intended?))
Checking the drives are in "Legacy" and AHCI
Disk formatting tool
Installing Kingston's SSD tool (A400 healthy no issues)
Disabled the damaged drive in boot menu as just having it enabled causes the working drive to not boot sometimes
Sometimes booting on the working drive with the broken one enabled causes the disk repair to start but always fails at 100%

The SUV400s has some 100Gb of data that would be nice to recover but won't shatter the earth if it is dead. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Why do you not think it has been irredeemably taken over by malware?

It hasn't touched anything online since the 20th besides a google drive notification and spotify trying to update itself and failing. Could be possible but can't confirm.

I would first try an installer that wasn’t old. Trying to install unsupported Windows versions after they are no longer supported is difficult even for someone who knows how to avoid issues caused by installing unsupported versions. Installing Windows not in Legacy mode is another suggestion

The old installer couldn't even be used so I got the latest version soon after. The latest is currently installed.

So if you didn’t use the older installer. Can you remove mentioning from your question. I would remove the drive with data, install a new drive and install Windows, then use an enclosure to harvest the data. Given the age of the equipment I would bet that the drive is failing
